# Sharing data in spring session attributes

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-security

Am using spring security and spring MVC. Am keeping a data in session attribute in unAuthenticated request(security:none in spring security). I tried printing the session id.After that i logged into the application. here new session is created. i tried printing the session id. both are different. but when i access the data placed in session attribute. it exist. In my understanding as new session is created after login, data should get lost or Is spring is sharing the session attributes ?
below is the code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persistFKey")
public @ResponseBody String persistFKey(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res,ModelMap modelMap) {
    System.out.println("SEssion ID ----persistKey ----"+request.getSession().getId());
    String fkey = request.getParameter("fkey");
    modelMap.addAttribute("fkey", fkey);    
    return "success";
}
```

In spring security xml, i gave

```
<sec:http security="none" pattern="/portal/persistFKey" />
```

After login, while invoking the new page am getting the data kept in session attribute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/renderScreen")
public String renderScreen(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
@ModelAttribute("srceenModel") ScreenModel srceenModel,ModelMap modelMap) {
    System.out.println("SEssion ID ----renderBooking----"+request.getSession().getId());
    System.out.println("SessionKey persisted --------"+(String)modelMap.get("fkey"));
}
```

Both are in same spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Spring Security changes the user's session id on login to avoid [Session Fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) attacks.

It is also nice enough to [migrate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation) the user's old session data to the new one.

You can change this behaviour via `<session-management session-fixation-protection="..." />`